# ADHM construction of gravitational instantons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, gravity, string-theory, instantons

Is there a ADHM-like construction for gravitational instantons?
Could somebody explain why there is not such construction?

Answer (score 1):

There is an ADHM-like construction for self-dual solutions to Einstein field equations.

For a pedagogical introduction see section 6.2 of the book: "Twistor Geometry and Field theory" by Ward.